# Using both HTTP Basic Authentication and Ws-Security together

Tags: c#, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to write a C# client application which consumes a SOAP 1.2 web service. This service is protected by both HTTP Basic authentication and WS-Security authentication, with different credentials for each. It's not my web service so I can't change it.

In my .config file, I have:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpsBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

In my code, I use this to set the WS-Security credentials:

```
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = header.UniqueId;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = header.Password;
```

When I do this, the WS-Security header is added to the SOAP message successfully but the HTTP Authorisation Header is missing. I've tried adding that one manually using:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                       httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = 
                "Basic " +
                Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(httpAuthUser + ":" +
                httpAuthPassword));

            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

But that code seems to be ignored.